# Getting Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address = 0x1a1090010) in core bluetooth framework while accessing characteristic.UUID.UUIDString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I am trying to compare local characteristic uuid string with delegates callback characteristic uuid string like below:

```
if([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:CHAR1_UUID]){
//But I'm getting bad access error here

}else if([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString isEqualToString:CHAR2_UUID]){                    

}
```

Can someone help me how to proceed further?

Comment: did u try to log UUID.UUIDString ?

Comment: Did you check that `characteristic.UUID` isn't nil.  Did you set a breakpoint and use the debugger?